# How can I check whether a URL is valid using `urlparse`?

Tags: python, urllib2, url-parsing, urlparse

I want to check whether a URL is valid, before I open it to read data.

I was using the function `urlparse` from the `urlparse` package:

```
if not bool(urlparse.urlparse(url).netloc):
 # do something like: open and read using urllin2
```

However, I noticed that some valid URLs are treated as broken, for example:

```
url = upload.wikimedia.org/math/8/8/d/88d27d47cea8c88adf93b1881eda318d.png
```

This URL is valid (I can open it using my browser).

Is there a better way to check if the URL is valid?

Comment: prepend http:// to url without it

Comment: @xfx But I have a lot of links, and I don't know if it will start with http:// or it will not, if it is a valid url or not. I want to write a function, which will tell me this avoiding this types of mistakes.

Comment: If you're going to open it with urllib2 anyway, can't you just open it first and check if the return code equals 200?

Comment: @Ziva this case, I think the regexp is the best way

Comment: If it's mainly the http:// that's the issue, `if(url[:7] != 'http://'):`...`url = 'http://' + url`

Comment: using a try/except would be the best way to go

Answer (score 14):

TL;DR: You can't actually. Every answer given already misses 1 or more cases.

1. String is **google.com** (invalid since no scheme, even though a browser assumes by default http). Urlparse will be missing scheme and netloc. So `all([result.scheme, result.netloc, result.path])` seems to work for this case
2. String is **http://google** (invalid since .com is missing). Urlparse will be missing only path. Again `all([result.scheme, result.netloc, result.path])` seems to catch this case
3. String is **http://google.com/** (correct). Urlparse will populate scheme, netloc and path. So for this case `all([result.scheme, result.netloc, result.path])` works fine
4. String is **http://google.com** (correct). Urlparse will be missing only path. So for this case `all([result.scheme, result.netloc, result.path])` ***seems to give a false negative***

*So from the above cases you see that the one that comes closest to a solution is `all([result.scheme, result.netloc, result.path])`. But this works only in cases where the url contains a path (even if that is the / path).*

**Even if you try to enforce a path (i.e `urlparse(urljoin(your_url, "/"))` you will still get a false positive in case 2**

Maybe something more complicated like

```
final_url = urlparse(urljoin(your_url, "/"))
is_correct = (all([final_url.scheme, final_url.netloc, final_url.path]) 
              and len(final_url.netloc.split(".")) > 1)
```

Maybe you also want to skip scheme checking and assume http if no scheme.
But even this will get you up to a point. Although it covers the above cases, it doesn't fully cover cases where a url contains an ip instead of a hostname. For such cases you will have to validate that the ip is a correct ip. And there are more scenarios as well. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL to think even more cases

Comment: urljoin and urlparse end up calling urlsplit which may throw a ValueError if there are brackets (IPv6) in what it thinks is the netloc, so exception handling is necessary too

Answer (score 13):

You can check if the url has the scheme:

```
>>> url = "no.scheme.com/math/12345.png"
>>> parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
>>> bool(parsed_url.scheme)
False
```

If it's the case, you can replace the scheme and get a *real* valid url:

```
>>> parsed_url.geturl()
"no.scheme.com/math/12345.png"
>>> parsed_url = parsed_url._replace(**{"scheme": "http"})
>>> parsed_url.geturl()
'http:///no.scheme.com/math/12345.png'
```

Comment: +1 for the trick with replacing the tuple which I find very elegant (and didn't know about). The only problem here is that the returned url contains three slashes after the scheme as the url with no scheme is interpreted as `path` instead of `netloc`. A simple `.replace('///', '//')` does the trick for me at least.

Comment: You missed `import urlparse`

Comment: @alexey_efimov, the question already said "I was using the argparse package".

Comment: Else, you can simply use `import urllib; urllib.parse.urlparse(url, scheme='http')` to get the same result..

Answer (score 5):

You can try the function below which checks `scheme`, `netloc` and `path` variables which comes after parsing the url. Supports both Python 2 and 3.

```
try:
    # python 3
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urlparse

def url_validator(url):
    try:
        result = urlparse(url)
        components = [result.scheme, result.path]
        if result.netloc != "":
            components.append(result.netloc)
        return all(components)
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: Fails on a valid URL. `>>> url_validator("file:///some_file.txt")
False`

Comment: made minor changes, you can try again

Answer (score 1):

Url without schema is actually invalid, your browser is just clever enough to suggest http:// as schema for it. It may be a good solution to check if url doesn't have schema (`not re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z]+://', url)`) and prepend `http://` to it.